# How can I read the tag value inside svg tag in testcafe

Tags: angular, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

There are multiple child elements present in the svg tag and I want to read the value of those tags, How can I do that?

I have tried following thigs

1. Tried to read the value using the child function
2. Tried to read the value using the css class name, but not working

Answer (score 0):

Please share a simple sample. I cannot reproduce the issue based on your description. My example works fine:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
        <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
        <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
      </g>
      <g fill="black" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
        <circle cx="140" cy="140" r="25" />
        <circle cx="160" cy="160" r="25" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
//test.js
import { Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture('My fixture')
  .page('./index.html');
test('First test', async t => {
  const div = Selector('div');
  const svg = div.find('svg');
  const firstFigure = svg.child(0);
  const secondFigure = svg.child(1);

  await t
    .expect(firstFigure().getAttribute('fill')).eql('white')
    .expect(secondFigure().getAttribute('fill')).eql('black')
    .expect(firstFigure.find('circle').getAttribute('cx')).eql('40')
    .expect(secondFigure.find('circle').getAttribute('cx')).eql('140')

});
```